# PhaseAnimator on view in ForEach not always working

Tags: swiftui

A small example to reproduce:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var shown = true
  @State private var haveTwo = true

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 30) {
      Toggle("Show Frame", isOn: $shown).padding()
      Toggle("Have Two", isOn: $haveTwo).padding()
      HStack {
        ForEach(0 ..< (haveTwo ? 2 : 1), id: \.self) { x in
          Text("\(x): Foo")
            .padding(25)
            .phaseAnimator([false, true]) { content, phase in
              content.overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                  .stroke(.green, lineWidth: phase ? 1 : 5)
                  .opacity(shown ? 1 : 0)
              )
            }.padding()
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that we start with **two** views inside the `HStack`.  When this runs, contrary to my expectations only the trailing (rightmost) one is animated.  Going back and forth between one (1) and two (2) views in the `HStack` does not change anything.

If I change the code to

```swift
...
  @State private var haveTwo = false
...
```

that is, start with a single view in the `HStack` then both views in the HStack are animated.

What am I missing here?  Or is that a bug?

Comment: I cannot reproduce. The whole view freezes when I try to switch to one view though, which seems to be related to https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737912

Comment: Thanks. FYI: I can reproduce reliably (exactly as described).  Tried as macos target on 14.1.1 (both X86 and M1).

Comment: Ah, I thought this was iOS. If it doesn't work on macOS but does on iOS, then it's probably a bug then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this animates on iOS, it should be safe to assume that this is not intentional. From my experiments, when you have two phase animators, it only animates the first one correctly if the second one's animation updates the layout of the first one in some way.

As a workaround, you can use just one phase animator:

```
PhaseAnimator([false, true]) { phase in
    HStack {
        ForEach(0 ..< (haveTwo ? 2 : 1), id: \.self) { x in
            ZStack {
                Text("\(x): Foo")
                    .padding(25)

                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                    .stroke(.green, lineWidth: phase ? 1 : 5)
                    .opacity(shown ? 1 : 0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Try running this code and resize the window. If the window is small enough that the resizing circle "pushes" the text "Foo" upwards, then "Foo" animates correctly. If the window is large enough that the circle only resizes the spacer in between, "Foo" doesn't animate.

```
VStack {
    PhaseAnimator([true, false]) { phase in
        Text("Foo").foregroundStyle(phase ? .white : .blue)
    }
    Spacer()
    PhaseAnimator([false, true]) { phase in
        Circle().frame(width: phase ? 50 : 100, height: phase ? 50 : 100)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is definitely not working as intended.  If you animate the text in your example—e.g., `Text(phase ? "Foo" : "Bar")` it animates without the spacer and with or without the foreground style modifier too.

Comment: @giik I think changing the text would change its frame too, and that’s why it’s animating correctly. This is probably something to do with layouting.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to tell if `Text(phase ? "Foo" : "Foo")`, which should not result in a frame change, animates on its own, though `Text(phase ? "Foo" : "Bar").frame(width: 300, height: 100)` (in a sufficiently large frame so the text would not matter) does.